# How to stop my function?

Tags: python-3.x, break

How do i get my function to stop, when a condition has been met? 
for example in my following code, when the user inputs: "`q`" for (quit), i want my function to simply stop. 
i've tried using the "`break`" statement, but it's not working.

```
def main():
    shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    while shape != 'triangle' and shape != 'square' and shape != 'q':
            print("Unknown shape. Please try again")
            shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    if shape == "q":
        print("Goodbye")  
        break #Python not happy with the indentation.

def get_valid_size():
    size = int(input("Enter size: "))
    while size < 1:
        print("Value must be at least 1")
        size = int(input("Enter size: "))
main()
get_valid_size()
```

when i run it, it executes:

`Enter shape to draw (q to quit): q
Goodbye
Enter size:`

i don't want it to ask for size.

Comment: what do you mean by stop?

Comment: @XiaotianPei i have a continuation for this code. when the user inputs "q", i dont want the function to continue doing the continuation. I dont know how to explain it in a programming way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`return`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) will exit a function, returning control to whatever had originally called the function.  If you want to learn more, the phrase to google is "Return statements."

`break` will exit a loop, [as described here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop).

Try something like:

```
def main():
    shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    while shape != 'triangle' and shape != 'square' and shape != 'q':
            print("Unknown shape. Please try again")
            shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    if shape == "q":
        print("Goodbye")  
        return
    get_valid_size()

def get_valid_size():
    size = int(input("Enter size: "))
    while size < 1:
        print("Value must be at least 1")
        size = int(input("Enter size: "))
main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the program is still not working as expected. it still continues to do the next step, when it shouldn't. i have edited my post to show the continuation of the program.

Comment: That's because of the way you have organized your code.  You are calling main() and then (once main is complete, and control has RETURNED from it) you are calling get_valid_size().  I recommend calling get_valid_size from INSIDE main() after your check.  Does that make sense?  I updated the answer to reflect what I'm talking about.  Eventually you would want to completely rewrite this code.

Comment: As an aside, you should spend some time reading about "Control Flow" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) to better understand how to mentally walk through a program in the same way a computer would!  It will make it much easier to solve this kind of problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`break` is only used to exit `for` loops, `while` loops, and `try` loops.

`return` will exit a function with a specified value. Simply using `return` will return a `None` value, while using `return True` or `return False` will return true and false, respectively. You can also return a variable, for example, to return a variable `x` you would use `return x`.

Comment: Clarifying note: that technically wouldn't return the variable "x", but rather it would return the value stored in "x"